# Simple Rock Paper Scissors

Tags: c++, game, c++11, rock-paper-scissors

I made a Rock Paper Scissors game. It works fine but I would like to know how can I improve it further.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <limits>

namespace
{
    enum Winner { Tie, Player, Computer, WinnerCount };
    enum Items { Rock, Paper, Scissors, ItemsCount };

    template<typename T, std::size_t N>
    using Matrix = std::array<std::array<T, N>, N>;
}


std::string user_choice(const std::array<std::string, Items::ItemsCount>& data)
{
    std::string result;
    static auto comp = [&result](const std::string& str) { return str == result; };
    bool is_input_valid = false;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter your choice, rock, paper, or scissors: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, result);

        is_input_valid = !(std::cin.fail() || std::none_of(data.begin(), data.end(), comp));

        if (!is_input_valid) {
            std::cout << "Not valid input.\n";
        }

        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
    } while (!is_input_valid);

    return result;
}

bool play_again()
{
    char result;
    bool is_input_valid = false;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Do you want to play again? [y/n]: ";
        std::cin >> result;

        result = std::toupper(result);

        is_input_valid = !(std::cin.fail() || (result != 'Y' && result != 'N'));

        if (!is_input_valid)
        {
            std::cout << "Not valid input.\n";
        }

        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    } while (!is_input_valid);

    return result == 'Y';
}

int main()
{
    // Set up game
    const Matrix<Winner, Winner::WinnerCount> table
    {
        {  // Rock      Paper      Scissors
            { Tie,      Computer,  Player   }, // Rock
            { Player,   Tie,       Computer }, // Paper
            { Computer, Player,    Tie      }, // Scissors
        }
    };

    const std::array<std::string, Items::ItemsCount> data
    {
        "rock",
        "paper",
        "scissors"
    };

    std::map<std::string, Items> binding_items
    {
       { data[Items::Rock],      Items::Rock     },
       { data[Items::Paper],     Items::Paper    },
       { data[Items::Scissors],  Items::Scissors },
    };

    const std::array<std::string, Winner::WinnerCount> winner_result
    {
       "It's a tie!\n\n",
       "You win!\n\n",
       "You lose!\n\n"
    };

    std::mt19937 engine{ std::random_device()() };
    auto dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<>(0, Items::ItemsCount - 1);

    // Game loop
    do
    {
        std::cout << "\n\n\tRock Paper Scissors Game\n\n";

        const auto user_chose = user_choice(data);
        const Items player = binding_items[user_chose];

        const Items computer = static_cast<Items>(dist(engine));
        const auto computer_chose = data[computer];

        std::cout << "\n\nYou entered: " << user_chose << '\n';
        std::cout << "Computer chose: " << computer_chose << '\n';

        std::cout << winner_result[table[player][computer]];
    } while (play_again());
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks pretty good at first glance! I'd say your main problem is "`#define ONE 1`" — you've gone out of your way to parameterize things that can't actually be changed in real life without massive changes elsewhere in the game logic. For example, you've set

```
enum Items { Rock, Paper, Scissors, ItemsCount };
```

which looks awesome... until someone decides to actually *use* that flexibility by changing it to

```
enum Items { Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock, ItemsCount };
```

and suddenly nothing compiles anymore. (They also have to change the local variables `table` and `data` and `binding_item` inside `main`, and the text of the `cout` inside `user_choice`, and maybe some more stuff too. By the way: variable names are important! `data` and `table` are not good names!)

The over-parameterization antipattern tends to travel along with the `std::array` antipattern — see ["The 'array size constant' antipattern"](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/08/06/array-size/) (2020-08-06). Somehow, people who've caught the "named constants > magic numbers" virus also tend to have caught the "std::array > core language" virus as well. Where you write

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
using Matrix = std::array<std::array<T, N>, N>;

const Matrix<Winner, Winner::WinnerCount> table
{
    {  // Rock      Paper      Scissors
        { Tie,      Computer,  Player   }, // Rock
        { Player,   Tie,       Computer }, // Paper
        { Computer, Player,    Tie      }, // Scissors
    }
};
```

an expert C++ programmer would probably just write

```
Winner table[3][3] = {
    // Rock      Paper      Scissors
    {  Tie,      Computer,  Player   }, // Rock
    {  Player,   Tie,       Computer }, // Paper
    {  Computer, Player,    Tie      }, // Scissors        
};
```

Incidentally, did you notice your bug above? You dimensioned your `table` by `WinnerCount`, but you index into it using values of `Item`. You're simply getting lucky that `WinnerCount` (win, lose, tie) happens to be the same as `ItemCount` (rock, paper, scissors).

---

Be aware that

```
std::mt19937 engine{ std::random_device()() };
```

is a relatively low-entropy way to initialize a Mersenne Twister: it has 19937 bits of state, and you're seeding it with only 32 random bits. But C++ doesn't offer any concise way to seed a PRNG properly, so actually what you've got *is* the state of the art.

---

```
const Items computer = static_cast<Items>(dist(engine));
```

Throughout, you use plural words where singular would be more appropriate, and relatively abstract nouns (`data`, `table`, `computer`) where more concrete ones would be appropriate. I'd write:

```
Item computers_choice = static_cast<Item>(dist(engine));
```

indicating that what we've got now is not a computer but rather the computer player's *choice* of what to throw; and it is not multiple Items but rather a single Item. (I'd probably rename `Item` to `Gesture`, too.)

---

Your `user_choice` function returns `std::string`, which you then have to parse *again* in `main`. It should just return the `Item` it extracted, directly, instead of the string.

Also, the logic around the `is_input_valid` boolean seems pretty baroque. Think about how the code could be simplified by using a `return` or `break` statement inside the loop.

```
if (std::getline(std::cin, result)) {
    if (map_of_strings_to_gestures.contains(result)) {
        return map_of_strings_to_gestures.at(result);
    }
}
std::cout << "Not valid input.\n";
// and go around again
```

Also, try hitting Ctrl-D (or Ctrl-Z on Windows) at this prompt. That'll close stdin, which makes `cin.fail()` true, which means the input isn't valid... and then your code just goes into an infinite loop, doesn't it? I think you actually want to *break out* of the loop when you see EOF or an error — not stay in the loop!

---

For configuring the gestures, I think you should investigate [X-macros](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2021/02/01/x-macros/). Here's my take: https://godbolt.org/z/8qhdcPWT5 The entirety of the "configuration" for the game is expressed in a single table at the top of the code:

```
#define GESTURES \
    X(Rock,     "rock",     BEATS(Scissors)) \
    X(Scissors, "scissors", BEATS(Paper)) \
    X(Paper,    "paper",    BEATS(Rock))
```

and I've also tested it with this configuration:

```
#define GESTURES \
    X(Rock,     "rock",     BEATS(Scissors) BEATS(Lizard)) \
    X(Scissors, "scissors", BEATS(Paper) BEATS(Lizard)) \
    X(Paper,    "paper",    BEATS(Rock) BEATS(Spock)) \
    X(Lizard,   "lizard",   BEATS(Spock) BEATS(Paper)) \
    X(Spock,    "spock",    BEATS(Scissors) BEATS(Rock))
```

(My version also eliminates the dependencies on `<map>`, `<algorithm>`, and of course `<limits>`.)

---

An obvious "next step" for this program would be to refactor it so that you can print a customized verb for each outcome:

```
Enter your choice (rock, scissors, paper): rock
You entered: rock
Computer chose: paper
Paper covers rock — you lose!

Enter your choice (rock, scissors, paper): scissors
You entered: scissors
Computer chose: paper
Scissors cuts paper — you win!
```

and so on.

Comment: Technically, since `std::random_device::operator` returns `unsigned int`, we're seeding with *an implementation-defined number of bits*, minimum 16.